# Disable print in microsoft office word

Tags: printing, ms-word

Hello is there a possible way to disable print in ms word office? under file > print  . I wanted to disable that for my printing application so I can track print jobs thru my c# application Thanks!

Comment: Either uninstall/disable the printer, or set the xps writer as default printer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click "File" -> "Options" -> "Display" tab.
2. Uncheck box for "Print document properties".

Comment: will that disable the print option in file tab